# ListChangeListener - correct change order

Tags: java, javafx

What is the correct change order?

In the documentation here - [click](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.base/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html), we can see the following example:

```
 ObservableList<Item> theList = ...;

 theList.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Item>() {
     public void onChanged(Change<Item> c) {
         while (c.next()) {
             if (c.wasPermutated()) {
                 for (int i = c.getFrom(); i < c.getTo(); ++i) {
                      //permutate
                 }
             } else if (c.wasUpdated()) {
                      //update item
             } else {
                 for (Item remitem : c.getRemoved()) {
                     remitem.remove(Outer.this);
                 }
                 for (Item additem : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                     additem.add(Outer.this);
                 }
             }
         }
     });

 }
```

BUT below the sample code there is:

> Note: in case the change contains multiple changes of different type,
> these changes must be in the following order: **permutation change(s),
> add or remove changes, update changes**. This is because permutation changes cannot go after add/remove changes as they would change the position of added elements. And on the other hand, update changes must go after add/remove changes because they refer with their indexes to the current state of the list, which means with all add/remove changes applied.

Is the example wrong then? Or maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three types of changes that can be fired by an `ObservableList`:

1. Permutation (a change in order)
2. Addition/removal (or replacement, which is just a simultaneous addition and removal)
3. An update (a change in an element's property, requires [an "extractor"](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.base/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList(javafx.util.Callback)))

A single *change* can be **only one of** those types. However, a single `Change` *instance* can carry multiple *changes*. That's why you have to iterate over the `Change` instance by calling `next()` in a `while` loop.

The documentation you quote:

> Note: in case the change contains multiple changes of different type, these changes must be in the following order: permutation change(s), add or remove changes, update changes.

Is regarding the order of changes returned by said `next()` method. Here the order is important because the `Change` must report the list *as it currently exists*.

That documentation does not dictate the order you *query* the type of change. If the change was not a permutation then `c.wasPermutated()` simply returns `false` and the code moves on. Same with the other types of changes. Note that, because of how the API is designed, if a change is neither a permutation nor an update then it *must be* an addition or removal (or replacement).

So the example is not wrong. If you wanted you could write it as:

```java
while (c.next()) {
  if (c.wasPermutated()) {
    // process perumutation
  } else if (c.wasRemoved() || c.wasAdded()) {
    // process removal, addition, or replacement
  } else {
    // process update
  }
}
```

But that does not change the behavior of the code.